# Reading parallel record in java from database

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot

I have one database and in this we have millions of records. We are reading the record one by one using java and inserting those record to another system on daily basis after end of day. We have been told to make it faster.

I told them we will create `multiple thread using thread pool` and these thread will read data `parallelly` and inject into another system but I dont know how can we stop our thread to read same data again. how can make it faster and achieve data consistency as well. I mean how can we make this process faster using `multithreading` in `java` or is there any other way ,other than multithreading to achieve it?

Comment: ‘JdbcPagingItemReader’ might give you an idea.

Comment: I not sure (it will depends of your env) but if querying data is your issue, parallel queries will be even worse. Paging the queries and get small number of records could be a solution as well as processing the result sets in parallel. They are different operations.

Comment: Thanks @btafarelo can you explain more probably in answer  or share some link to read?

Comment: @rashmi mark's answer is what I would tell you. Just focus on the cause before any refactoring. Make sure how long takes to retrieve a row and compare in retrieve many, 1000 for instance. If the slowness is in your database, a query plan or a dba will point you the issue. Unfortunately I don't have any material to help you just my experience in this case.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution for your task would be taking the ids of records in your database, splitting them into chunks (e.g. with size 1000 each) and calling `JpaRepository.findAllById(Iterable<ID>)` within `Runnable`s passed to `ExecutorService.submit()`.

If you don't want to do it manually then you could have a look into Spring Batch. It is designed particularly for bulk transformation of large amounts of data.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should identify the slowest part in this flow and try to optimize it step by step.

In the described flow you could:

1. Try to reduce the number of "roundtrips" between the java application (in coming from the driver driver) and the database: Stop reading records one by one and move to bulk reading. Namely, read, say, 2000 records at once from the db into memory and process the whole bulk. Consider even larger numbers (like 5000) but you should measure this really, it depends on the memory of the java application and other factors. Anyway, if there is an issue - discard the bulk.
2. The data itself might not be organized correctly: when you read the bulk of data you might need to order it by some criteria, so make sure it doesnt make a full table scan, define indices properly etc
3. If applicable, talk to your DBA, he/she might provide additional insights about data management itself: partitioning, storage related optimizations, etc.
4. If all this fails and reading from the db is still a bottleneck, consider the flow redesign (for instance - throw messages to kafka if you have one), these might be naturally partitioned so you could scale out the whole process, but this might be beyond the scope of this question.